# Heroku deployment error when deploying bot

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js

my discord bot is not working well with Heroku, anyone know the cause? I'm going to give the error message I am receiving while trying to deploy the bot, if you guys need info about the files in my program just lmk! Thanks

````
2021-08-31T03:57:41.760749+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-08-31T03:57:42.368542+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-08-31T03:57:44.139912+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-08-31T03:57:44.213728+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057396+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057418+00:00 app[worker.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057419+00:00 app[worker.1]:           ^^^
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057419+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057419+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057420+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057420+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057420+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057420+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057421+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057421+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057421+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057421+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:4:20)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057421+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
2021-08-31T03:57:44.057422+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

discord.js v13 requires node v16.6 or later, which your Heroku dyno doesn't have. According to [the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version), to specify a custom node version you need to include this in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  // ...
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x" // Or whatever node version you want
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You save me, thanks a lot 